# Curve that bounds a fixed-length sliding line segment

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves

Consider a line segment of length $d$ and an initial position $(0, 0)$, $(0, d)$ on a Cartesian coordinate system. Now consider an $\epsilon$ move such that the new position is $(\epsilon, 0)$, $(0, \sqrt{d^2-\epsilon^2})$ with $\epsilon \in [0, d]$.

Now, if we let $\epsilon$ vary continuously from $0$ to $d$ it seems like the segment movement is bounded by a curve which I am trying to find its equation. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The length of "the" segment has changed. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Paul you are right I fixed it (it wasn't intentional)

Comment: This is called the envelope of your line segments (see Wikipedia for example). The straight line through each segment has the form  $F(x,y,\epsilon)=y-\frac{\epsilon - x}{\epsilon} \sqrt{d^2-\epsilon^2} = 0$. Elimination of $\epsilon$ as per the Wikipedia article may not be possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Did not know that this kind of curve is called an envelope

Comment: @Paul By rearranging and squaring, $F=0$ can be transformed into a polynomial in $t$, which can then be eliminated by requiring the discriminant vanish (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#Envelope_of_a_family_of_curves). The resulting implicit equation isn’t particularly pretty, though.

Comment: I saw that too - surprisingly un-pretty given the seeming simplicity of the set up..

Answer (score 0):

As Paul mentions in a comment, it looks like you’re talking about what’s called the [*envelope* of a family of curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)), that is, a curve that is tangent to each member of the family at some point. In this case, the family of curves consists of the lines $\frac x\epsilon + \frac y{\sqrt{d^2-\epsilon^2}} = 1$, parameterized by $\epsilon$. The envelope satisfies the system $$F(\epsilon,x,y) = \frac x\epsilon + \frac y{\sqrt{d^2-\epsilon^2}} - 1 = 0 \\ \frac\partial{\partial\epsilon}F(\epsilon,x,y) = \frac x{\epsilon^2} - {\epsilon y\over\left(d^2-\epsilon^2\right)^{3/2}} = 0.$$

Eliminating $\epsilon$ in Mathematica produces the equation $$y^4 \left(3 x^2-3 d^2\right)+y^2 \left(3 d^4+21 d^2 x^2+3 x^4\right)+y^6=d^6-3 d^4 x^2+3 d^2 x^4-x^6.\tag{*}$$ The following plot shows the graph of this curve in the first quadrant for a few values of $d$:

[image: First-quadrant envelopes]

The equation of this family of lines can be turned into a polynomial equation in $\epsilon$ by clearing denominators, rearranging and squaring: $$(\epsilon - x)^2(d^2-\epsilon^2)-y^2\epsilon^2 = 0,$$ which expands into $$\epsilon^2 - 2x\epsilon^3 + (x^2+y^2-d^2)\epsilon^2+2d^2x\epsilon-d^2x^2=0.$$ The definition of the envelope is equivalent to $t$ being a double root of this equation, so you can use the formula for the [discriminant of a quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4) to eliminate $\epsilon$. After removing an extraneous factor of $16x^2y^2$, you will be left with (*).

Comment: It is a classical envelope (sliding ladder problem) with solution an astroid.